# Trigger Infinite Scroll based on target position

Tags: jquery, containers, offset, infinite-scroll

I am trying to trigger / allow a new set of images to be loaded when the bottom of the window scroll bar has reached the position of a target div.

Here is the formula for triggering when scrollbar reaches the bottom of the page with a slight offset, 50, and works flawlessly.

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    // Page height
    var pageHeight  = $(document).height();
    // Window height
    var winH = $(window).height();
    // Scrollbar position
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    // Formula
    var dist = pageHeight - (scrollPos + winH);
    // When to load new images with a slight offset
    var load = dist < 50;
    if (load) {
        addItems();
    }
});
```

But, instead if I want to use the position of a target `div.infinite-scroll` what is the calculation / formula needed? I thought that I could substitute the target div's offset in place of, 50, but did not work for me.

```
var targetPos = $(Infinite_Scroll.container).offset().top;
var load = dist < targetPos;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for my needs and could help others. If you substitute the target container for the `pageHeight`in the calculation than Infinite Scroll will be triggered as the window scrollbar reaches the position of the target instead of the bottom of the page.

```
// Before
var dist = pageHeight - (scrollPos + winH);
// Change
var dist = $(Infinite_Scroll.container).offset().top - (scrollPos + winH);

$(window).scroll( function() {
    // Page height
    var pageHeight  = $(document).height();
    // Window height
    var winH = $(window).height();
    // Scrollbar position
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    // Formula
    var dist = $(Infinite_Scroll.container).offset().top - (scrollPos + winH);
    // When to load new images with a slight offset
    var load = dist < 50;
    if (load) {
        addItems();
    }
});
```